# Unexplainable white space on my footer

Tags: html, css, whitespace, footer

I'm in the process of creating a website (a beginner obviously) and for some reason, on one of my pages, the footer section is MUCH longer than it is supposed to be. Its werid because on other pages, it looks fine. I used the exact same code on a new page and the footer is all out of whack. Here's what I get when I inspect the element on Chrome:

```
 <div id="skel-layers-inactiveWrapper" style="height: 100%;">
```

I can't find anything regarding inactive Wrappers or anything of the sorts in any of my css files either. Thanks for the help.

Here is the entire code in context. The only tags it is embedded within are html and body tags.

```
<footer id="footer">
<!-- Contact -->
<h2 class="major"><span><a href ="/contact.php"> Get in touch</a></span></h2>
<center><ul class="contact">
<li><a class="icon fa-facebook" href="#"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
<li><a class="icon fa-twitter" href="#"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
<li><a class="icon fa-google-plus" href="#"><span class="label">Google+</span></a></li>
 </ul></center>
        <!-- Copyright -->
            <div id="copyright">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li>&copy; All rights reserved 2014</li>
                </ul>
                                </div>

    </footer>
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? or use the new feature of SO or just even a screenshot?

Comment: Post a link to the website, so we can inspect it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, here it is:http://govpal.ca/register.php

Answer (score 2):

Assign a rule in your CSS to disable the skell-layers-inactiveWrapper effect:

```
#skel-layers-inactiveWrapper{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your script **skel-layers.min.js**. The ID `#skel-layers-inactiveWrapper` is getting updated through the script dynamically with a 'height' of '100%'.

If `#skel-layers-inactiveWrapper` is really an unwanted at this stage, just try to update the css of this to 'display: none'.

**The CSS:**

```
#skel-layers-inactiveWrapper {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems to be caused by this line.

```
<div id="skel-layers-inactiveWrapper" style="height: 100%;"></div>
```

You have to trace what script is adding the height: 100% css rule to this id.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is very easy,
these are solution steps

1. search and open the folder **js**
2. search and open the the file: **skel-layers.min**
3. into a file search **100%** and replace for : **0%**
4. ready